# groovy: is there a way to get variable name

Tags: groovy

Assume:

```
Map map_a = [ 'x': 1 ]
Map map_b = [ 'y': 2 ]
```

I'd like to know whether if there's a way (i.e.: `it.getVariableName` or `getVariableName(it)`) in groovy as below:

```
[ map_a, map_b ].each {
  it.getVariableName       =>  'map_a' or 'map_b'
}
```

I suppose `binding` or `metaClass` might help, but don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do what you are talking about without introducing a compiler extension (AST transformation or similar).  An object could have any number of references pointing to it and they could all have different names.

Comment: So, if `String a = 'xyz'` definied in Groovy, the variable name `a` actually isn't the char in memory but an address of `'xyz'` ? Which means, there's only `'xyz'` (value) was stored in memory, the variable name ( `'a'`) cannot?

Answer (score 0):

the answer from Jeff is correct.

but keep in mind that you could do a lot of things with closures & maps in groovy that could give you nice syntax results

```
def maps=[:]
maps.with{
    map_a = [ 'x': 1 ]
    map_b = [ 'y': 2 ]
}

maps.each{k,v->
    println "$k :: $v"
}
```

result:

```
map_a :: [x:1]
map_b :: [y:2]
```

Comment: So.. the only way to catch the "variable name" is to 'make variable name to a value stored in memory', is that right?

Comment: That's correct for a standard groovy version 3x.

Comment: "That's correct for a standard groovy version 3x." - Strictly speaking that isn't true.  We capture variables names for various purposes in Grails routinely, but we are using an AST transformation to do so.